Markov inequality implies light lower tail?
Let $X$ be a non-negative random variables taking integer values. Suppose we know that the expection $EX\ge t$. I find one says that by a simple application of Markov inequality
$$P(X\ge \frac{t}{C})\ge \frac{1}{2},$$
where $C>0$ can be a large constant.
I feel confused here: since Markov inequality tells us the upper tail is small $P(X\ge \lambda \cdot EX)\le \frac{1}{\lambda}$. How do we know that the lower tail is also small?
By the way, in the context, $X$ can have the form of the sum of independent character variables, or the sum of dependent character variables. In the former case, when $t$ is large enough, applying Chernoff's inequality will get the desired result. (But not Markov inequality.) I am not sure about the dependent sum case.

If $C$ can be any positive constant, i.e. doesn‘t have to be large we get:
Suppose $X\equiv2 \ $ ($X$ is constant) on any probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$.
Say $t=2$, then $\mathbb{E}(X)\geq 2$ and suppose $C=\frac{1}{2}$, then
$$P(X \geq \frac{t}{C})=P(X\geq 4)=0$$

The claim as stated is false.  Consider for any  positive integer $N > 2 t$ a random variable $X$ where $X = 0$ with probability $1-t/N$, $X = N$ with probability $t/N$.  Then $\mathbb E[X] = t$ but $\mathbb P(X \ge t/C) \le t/N < 1/2$.
